# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException when changing a property in sqlcontainer - Vaadin

Tags: java, sql, vaadin, hsqldb

Hi I'm getting SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException when trying to change properties of newly added item in sql container. I've got a very simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE person(
id int not null primary key,
name varchar(30),
surname varchar(30),
age int
)
```

I'm trying to set all properties one by one, but after first finishing (id), next one ends up with an exeption thrown:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10096 table: PERSON
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery.executeUpdateReturnKeys(TableQuery.java:588)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery.storeRow(TableQuery.java:284)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.itemChangeNotification(SQLContainer.java:1069)
at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.ColumnProperty.setValue(ColumnProperty.java:207)
at slawek.MyVaadinUI.init(MyVaadinUI.java:93)
at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:610)
```

Here's the code:

```
FormLayout form = new FormLayout();
    TextField idTextField = new TextField("Id");
    TextField nameTextField = new TextField("Name");
    TextField surnameTextField = new TextField("Surname");
    TextField ageTextField = new TextField("Age");
    Button submit = new Button("Add user");
    form.addComponents(idTextField, nameTextField, surnameTextField, ageTextField, submit);

    layout.addComponent(form);
    Item item = container.getItem(container.addItem());
    container.setAutoCommit(true);
    Property propertyId = item.getItemProperty("ID");
    Property propertyName = item.getItemProperty("NAME");
    Property propertySurname = item.getItemProperty("SURNAME");
    Property propertyAge = item.getItemProperty("AGE");

    propertyId.setValue(3);
    propertyName.setValue("someName"); // line number 93
    propertySurname.setValue("someSurname");
    propertyAge.setValue(51);
```

In the database all i can see is a new row added with an id number set only. The rest of fields are null.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the situation by separating the line below into two lines and check the fields of the object returned by container.addItem() before modifying them. If object has an ID with the rest of the fields null, then you should not use proertyId.setValue(3) because this has already been set.

```
Item item = container.getItem(container.addItem());
```

Comment: The thing is that it didn't work the day i posted my question, but the very next day i managed to launch it and it started without any problem. Maybe it's some eclipse, or hsqldb issue? Anyway since then it works ok